# All possible combinations of selected character substitution in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, combinations, substitution, gsub

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do every combination of selected character substitutions in ruby in a simple way.

An example:

```
    string = "this is a test"
    subs = ['a'=>'@','i'=>'!','s'=>'$']
    subs.combination.each { |c|
        string.gsub c
    }
```

would yield

```
    "this is @ test"
    "th!s !s a test"
    "thi$ i$ a te$t"
    "th!s !s @ test"
    "thi$ i$ @ te$t"
    "th!$ !$ a te$t"
    "th!$ !$ @ te$t"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to generate the combinations?

Comment: Its for an assignment in a computer security course I am taking. We are to write a password cracker that given a wordlist should crack a hashed password our professor has given us. The above is implemented already, albeit in a very ugly way where every combination is hardcoded in the script.

Comment: Do you need exactly your expected output, then I need to work more on my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = "this is a test"
subs = ['a'=>'@','i'=>'!','s'=>'$']

subs = subs.first.map(&:to_a)
1.upto(subs.length).each do |n|
  subs.combination(n).each do |a|
    p a.each_with_object(string.dup){|pair, s| s.gsub!(*pair)}
  end
end
```

Comment: If I am not wrong OP did wrong structure..`['a'=>'@','i'=>'!','s'=>'$']`.. it should be `Hash`.. Right ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit That is not a hash, it is an array including a hash with the `{}` omitted.

Comment: Ok. Its a array of Hash or only Hash.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do as below :

```
string = "this is a test"
subs = {'a'=>'@','i'=>'!','s'=>'$'}

keys = subs.keys
combinations = 1.upto(subs.size).flat_map { |i| keys.combination(i).to_a }

combinations.each do |ary|
  new_string = string.dup
  ary.each { |c| new_string.gsub!(c,subs) }
  puts new_string
end
```

**output**

```
this is @ test
th!s !s a test
thi$ i$ a te$t
th!s !s @ test
thi$ i$ @ te$t
th!$ !$ a te$t
th!$ !$ @ te$t
```

Comment: +1 This is similar to what I was typing until I got knocked off of wifi (on a commuter bus right now). I noticed you have an unused variable `new`

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks, I first thought, I would create `#map`, thus `new` there. After that I changed my decision, but forgot to remove `new` variable. Now I did.

Comment: Interesting to use a hash argument to `sub!`, but I don't think you needed to convert the match pattern into a regex, do you?

Comment: @sawa No it is unnecessary.. :-) thanks, same as I replied to *Mark*. I changed my plan, forgot to remove those. Anyway thanks for your review too.

Comment: @MarkThomas I did that to get `this is @ test`,`th!s is a test` and `thi$ is a test` .. Any mind blowing idea from you ? :-) My brain is not working any more on this.

Comment: @ArupRakshit the second `s` is not being replaced with `$` in your output.

Comment: @Abdo I used `sub` that's why.. Need to put `gsub` there.. Thanks for the pointer. I did a lots of experiment on it, after that I got fused to remove some parts from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do as follows using [`String#gsub(pattern, hash)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) :

```
string = "this is a test"
subs = {'a'=>'@','i'=>'!','s'=>'$'} # copied from @ArupRakshit
keys = subs.keys
```

And core code:

```
1.upto(keys.length).flat_map { |i| 
  keys.combination(i).flat_map { |c| string.gsub(/[#{c.join}]/, subs) } 
}
```

Output:

```
=> ["this is @ test",
 "th!s !s a test",
 "thi$ i$ a te$t",
 "th!s !s @ test",
 "thi$ i$ @ te$t",
 "th!$ !$ a te$t",
 "th!$ !$ @ te$t"]
```

Comment: Nice solution, Abdo, +1.  I wasn't aware that `gsub` can take a hash as an argument.  Good to know.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yup! Our solutions can be combined into the following: `keys.repeated_combination(keys.length).map { |c| string.gsub(/[#{c.uniq.join}]/, subs) }.uniq`

Comment: I like that.  What would you propose for my royalty?

Comment: @CarySwoveland haha :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
string = "this is a test"
subs   = [{"a"=>"@"}, {"i"=>"!"}, {"s"=>"$"}]

subs.repeated_combination(subs.size)
    .map {|e| string.gsub(/./) {|c| (g = e.find {|h| h.key?(c)}) ? g[c] : c}}
    .uniq
  #=> ["this is @ test", "th!s !s @ test", "thi$ i$ @ te$t", "th!$ !$ @ te$t",
  #    "th!s !s a test", "th!$ !$ a te$t", thi$ i$ a te$t"]
```

Explanation:

```
a = subs.repeated_combination(subs.size)
  # Enumerator...
  a.to_a 
  # [[{"a"=>"@"},{"a"=>"@"},{"a"=>"@"}], [{"a"=>"@"},{"a"=>"@"},{"i"=>"!"}],
  #  [{"a"=>"@"},{"a"=>"@"},{"s"=>"$"}], [{"a"=>"@"},{"i"=>"!"},{"i"=>"!"}],
  #  [{"a"=>"@"},{"i"=>"!"},{"s"=>"$"}], [{"a"=>"@"},{"s"=>"$"},{"s"=>"$"}],
  #  [{"i"=>"!"},{"i"=>"!"},{"i"=>"!"}], [{"i"=>"!"},{"i"=>"!"},{"s"=>"$"}],
  #  [{"i"=>"!"},{"s"=>"$"},{"s"=>"$"}], [{"s"=>"$"},{"s"=>"$"},{"s"=>"$"}]]

b = a.map {|e| string.gsub(/./) {|c| (g = e.find {|h| h.key?(c)}) ? g[c] : c}}
  #=> ["this is @ test", "th!s !s @ test", "thi$ i$ @ te$t", "th!s !s @ test",
  #    "th!$ !$ @ te$t", "thi$ i$ @ te$t", "th!s !s a test", "th!$ !$ a te$t",
  #    "th!$ !$ a te$t", "thi$ i$ a te$t"]
```

To see how `b` is computed, consider the second element of `a` that is passed to the block:

```
    e = [{"a"=>"@"},{"a"=>"@"},{"i"=>"!"}]
```

Because of the regex, `/./`, `gsub` passes each character `c` of `string` to the block

```
    {|c| (g = e.find {|h| h.key?(c)}) ? g[c] : c}
```

A search is made of `e` to determine if any of the three hashes has `c` as a key.  If one is found, namely, `g`, the character `c` is replaced with `g[c]`; else, the character is left unchanged.

Notice that the first two elements of `e` are the same.  Efficiency could be improved by changing the first line to:

```
    subs.repeated_combination(subs.size).map(&:uniq)
```

but efficiency is not one of the virtues of this approach.

Returning to the main calculation, the final step is:

```
b.uniq
  #=> ["this is @ test", "th!s !s @ test", "thi$ i$ @ te$t", "th!$ !$ @ te$t",
  #    "th!s !s a test", "th!$ !$ a te$t", "thi$ i$ a te$t"]
```

Comment: Oh yes! Great use of repeated_combination! +1

Answer (score 0):

A **one-line functional** solution

```
string = "this is a test"
subs = {'a'=>'@','i'=>'!','s'=>'$'}

(1..subs.size).flat_map { |n| subs.keys.combination(n).to_a }.map { |c| string.gsub(/[#{c.join}]/, subs) }
# => ["this is @ test", "th!s !s a test", "thi$ i$ a te$t", "th!s !s @ test", "thi$ i$ @ te$t", "th!$ !$ a te$t", "th!$ !$ @ te$t"]
```

Comment: Mine is a one liner... I only indented it you people wouldn't have to scroll.

Comment: I agree is better to make it in several lines to gain readability

Comment: According to the official rules, it qualifies as a one-liner if displayed on multiple lines merely to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling. I nice way of doing that here would be to start the second line with .map, positioned below .flat_map.  Ruby will have no problem with that (though IRB/Pry will).