# Show all substring replacement options in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I’m trying to show all possible options for substring replacements. For example, if I have this string:

```
my_string = “yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats”
```

and here are the different options that could be replaced:

```
substitutions = {“yellow” => “black”, “brown” => “grey”}
```

How would I get the following output?

```
["black dogs are cooler than brown cats", "black dogs are cooler than grey cats", "yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats", "yellow dogs are cooler than grey cats"]
```

So far I just have this, and as you can see, it’s not getting all options:

```
substitutions.each do |key, value|
    puts my_string.sub(key, value) if my_string.include? key
end
```

Comment: Eh. Your desired output seems incomplete; don't you want to account for the other two possibilities as well: `["yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats", "yellow dogs are cooler than grey cats"]`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
my_string = "yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats"
substitutions = {"yellow" => "black", "brown" => "grey"}

keys = substitutions.keys
arry_of_comb = 0.upto(substitutions.size).flat_map do |num|
  keys.combination(num).map do |ary| 
    my_string.gsub(/\b#{Regexp.union(ary)}\b/,substitutions) 
  end
end
arry_of_comb
# => ["yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats",
#     "black dogs are cooler than brown cats",
#     "yellow dogs are cooler than grey cats",
#     "black dogs are cooler than grey cats"]
```

Comment: Cool. How could I get it to work if there was two options for a substitution? For example, substitutions = {"yellow" => "black", "brown" => "grey", "brown" => "blue"}

Comment: @user2270029 get some idea from my similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22068328/2767755).

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is to turn this

```
substitutions = {“yellow” => “black”, “brown” => “grey”}
```

into this:

```
[{"yellow"=>"yellow", "brown"=>"brown"},
 {"yellow"=>"yellow", "brown"=>"grey"},
 {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"brown"},
 {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"grey"}]
```

Then you can trivially loop over the above and get your desired output (you initially omitted the identity transformation, but it's most straightforward to include it).  Here is one way to change `substitutions` into that:

```
substitutions.to_a[0].product(substitutions.to_a[1]).map do |ary|
  Hash[substitutions.keys.zip ary]
end
```

Then it's straightforward:

```
_.each do |h|
  p my_string.split.map {|word| h.fetch(word,word) }.join(' ')
end
"yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats"
"yellow dogs are cooler than grey cats"
"black dogs are cooler than brown cats"
"black dogs are cooler than grey cats"
```

here I opted for split -> sub each word -> rejoin over a global `sub` operation, since you presumably want to replace "brown" but not "brownie".  On the other hand this doesn't handle punctuation very gracefully, so you may opt for doing `sub` or some more sophisticated regex op.  Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic solution that works for any number of substitutions (not just two):

```
my_string = "yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats"
substitutions = {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"sweeter"}
keys = substitutions.keys           #=> ["yellow","brown","cooler"]
regx = /\b#{Regexp.union(keys)}\b/  #=> /\b(?:yellow|brown|cooler)\b/
axes = substitutions.to_a           #=> [["yellow", "black"], ["brown", "grey"], ["cooler", "sweeter"]]
maps = axes.shift.product(*axes).map{ |*vals| Hash[ keys.zip(*vals) ] }
maps.each{ |map| p map, my_string.gsub(regx){ |match| map[match] } }

#=> {"yellow"=>"yellow", "brown"=>"brown", "cooler"=>"cooler"}
#=> "yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats"

#=> {"yellow"=>"yellow", "brown"=>"brown", "cooler"=>"sweeter"}
#=> "yellow dogs are sweeter than brown cats"

#=> {"yellow"=>"yellow", "brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"cooler"}
#=> "yellow dogs are cooler than grey cats"

#=> {"yellow"=>"yellow", "brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"sweeter"}
#=> "yellow dogs are sweeter than grey cats"

#=> {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"brown", "cooler"=>"cooler"}
#=> "black dogs are cooler than brown cats"

#=> {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"brown", "cooler"=>"sweeter"}
#=> "black dogs are sweeter than brown cats"

#=> {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"cooler"}
#=> "black dogs are cooler than grey cats"

#=> {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"sweeter"}
#=> "black dogs are sweeter than grey cats"
```

The key here is the `product` call, which turns `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` into:

```
[[1, 3, 5],
 [1, 3, 6],
 [1, 4, 5],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [2, 3, 5],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 6]]
```

In other words, all the combinations from the calling array and all arrays passed in.

Using the regular expression with `gsub` makes it efficient, doing one pass through the string for each full set of replacements. The block form of `gsub` yields the found text, which is then used to look up the desired replacement (sometimes the same string as the original).

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats"

substitutions = {"yellow" => "black", "brown" => "grey"}

substitutions.each do |k,v|
  if my_string.include?(k)
    my_string.sub! k, v
  end
end

puts my_string
```

output : black dogs are cooler than grey cats

Comment: That does the one variation, but as I stated above I need all possible variations. Please see the desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
my_array = my_string.split.map(&:strip)

substitutions.to_a
             .repeated_permutation(subs.size)
             .map { |a| Hash[a.uniq] }
             .uniq
             .map { |h| my_array.map { |w| h.key?(w) ? h[w] : w }.join(' ') }
             .concat([my_string])
             .uniq
```

At the loss of some efficiency, either or both of the first two appearances of `uniq` could be omitted.

The steps:

```
my_string = "yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats"
substitutions = {"yellow"=>"black", "brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"neater"}

a = substitutions.to_a  # 27 elements
  #=> [["yellow", "black"], ["brown", "grey"], ["cooler", "neater"]] 
b = a.repeated_permutation(subs.size)
  #=> => #<Enumerator: [["yellow", "black"],...
  b.to_a
  #=> [[["yellow", "black"], ["yellow", "black"], ["yellow", "black"]],
   #   [["yellow", "black"], ["yellow", "black"], ["brown", "grey"]],
   #   [["yellow", "black"], ["yellow", "black"], ["cooler", "neater"]],
   #   [["yellow", "black"], ["brown", "grey"], ["yellow", "black"]],
   #   ...
   #   [["cooler", "neater"], ["cooler", "neater"], ["cooler", "neater"]]] 

c = b.map {|a| Hash[a.uniq]} # 27 elements
  #=> [{"yellow"=>"black"},
   #   {"brown"=>"grey", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #   {"cooler"=>"neater", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #   {"brown"=>"grey", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #   {"brown"=>"grey", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #   ...
   #   {"brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"neater", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #   ...
   #   {"cooler"=>"neater"}]

d = c.uniq
   #=> [{"yellow"=>"black"},
   #    {"brown"=>"grey", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #    {"cooler"=>"neater", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #    {"brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"neater", "yellow"=>"black"},
   #    {"brown"=>"grey"},
   #    {"brown"=>"grey", "cooler"=>"neater"},
   #    {"cooler"=>"neater"}] 

e = d.map {|h| my_array.map { |w| h.key?(w) ? h[w] : w }.join(' ') }
     .concat([my_string])
  #=> ["black dogs are cooler than brown cats",
  #    "black dogs are cooler than grey cats",
  #    "black dogs are neater than brown cats",
  #    "black dogs are neater than grey cats",
  #    "yellow dogs are cooler than grey cats",
  #    "yellow dogs are neater than grey cats",
  #    "yellow dogs are neater than brown cats",
  #    "yellow dogs are cooler than brown cats"] 

e.uniq
  # No effect here.  Only relevant for substitutions such as
  # "black=>"yellow" and "grey=>yellow", or "black"=>"black"
```