# All possible combinations of selected character substitution in a string in ruby - Improved

Tags: ruby

I am using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067184/all-possible-combinations-of-selected-character-substitution-in-a-string-in-ruby/22068328#22068328), but if I want to do multiple options for say the "s" substitution that you'll see below, it can only handle one. How do I make the code below work with substitutions more like this:

```
subs = {'a'=>['@'],'i'=>['!'],'s'=>['$','&'] }
```

Here was the original code and substitutions.

```
string = "this is a test"
subs = {'a'=>'@','i'=>'!','s'=>'$'}

keys = subs.keys
combinations = 1.upto(subs.size).flat_map { |i| keys.combination(i).to_a }

combinations.each do |ary|
  new_string = string.dup
  ary.each { |c| new_string.gsub!(c,subs) }
  puts new_string
end
```

Comment: Your `subs` is not a valid Ruby expression.

Comment: Yiu should write `subs = {'a'=>'@','i'=>'!', '*','s'=>'$', 's'=>'&'}` as `subs = {'a'=>'@','i'=>'!', '*','s'=>['$','&'] }`.. This is valid.

Comment: Thanks. I made the edit above, but it returns me items like this: "th!["$", "&"] !["$", "&"] @ te["$", "&"]t"

Comment: It is not good to be inconsistent. You should use an array all the way. `{'a' => ['@'], ...}`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I changed that above as well. How do I get the code to produce the output I want now? It's just substituting the arrays in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than your `subs`, the following one, which includes the information that replacement can vacuously apply, would be easier to handle:

```
subs = {"a" => ["a", "@"], "i" => ["i", "!"], "s" => ["s", "$", "&"]}
```

Using this, you should have sticked to my answer. The following is just a minor modification to my answer to your previous question:

```
string = "this is a test"

a = subs.values
a = a.first.product(*a.drop(1))

a.each do |a|
  p [subs.keys, a].transpose.each_with_object(string.dup){|pair, s| s.gsub!(*pair)}
end
```

which gives:

```
"this is a test"
"thi$ i$ a te$t"
"thi& i& a te&t"
"th!s !s a test"
"th!$ !$ a te$t"
"th!& !& a te&t"
"this is @ test"
"thi$ i$ @ te$t"
"thi& i& @ te&t"
"th!s !s @ test"
"th!$ !$ @ te$t"
"th!& !& @ te&t"
```