# All possible permutations or combinations of a selected character substitution's in a string in ruby w/ permutations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, combinations, permutation

How would I find all possible combinations or permutations of a substituted string? Similar to this answer, but this answer only shows different combinations with the same character in the position being substituted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22131499/1360374.

```
subs = {"a" => ["a", "@"], "i" => ["i", "!"], "s" => ["s", "$", "&"]}

string = "this is a test"

a = subs.values
a = a.first.product(*a.drop(1))

a.each do |a|
p [subs.keys, a].transpose.each_with_object(string.dup){|pair, s| s.gsub!(*pair)}
end
```

WHICH GIVES:

```
"this is a test"
"thi$ i$ a te$t"
"thi& i& a te&t"
"th!s !s a test"
"th!$ !$ a te$t"
"th!& !& a te&t"
"this is @ test"
"thi$ i$ @ te$t"
"thi& i& @ te&t"
"th!s !s @ test"
"th!$ !$ @ te$t"
"th!& !& @ te&t"
```

I AM TRYING TO GET ALL DIFFERENT PERMUTATIONS:

```
"this is a test"
"this i$ a te$t"
"thi& is a te&t"
"th!s !s a test"

etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
string = "this is a test"
p = ?a, ?i, ?s
q = ?@, ?!, [ ?$, ?& ]

replacements = Hash.new { |h, e| Array e }.tap do |h|
  p.zip( q ).each { |p, q| h[p] = p, *Array( q ) }
end
#=> {"a"=>["a", "@"], "i"=>["i", "!"], "s"=>["s", "$", "&"]}

puts string.split( '' ).map( &replacements.method( :[] ) ).reduce( &:product ).map { |e|
  e.flatten.join
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same result as the other answer; I am looking for all permutations of the substituted characters. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question thoroughly. Is this what you want? (Perhaps you devoted too much space describing the solution you _didn't want_ lol.)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I am sure your answer will help many other people, I noticed this is a hot topic in forums which many people can't figure out...

Comment: `Array#product` is the key method here, and `Array#flatten`, which should imo generally be avoided, may have its usecase here.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Boris's but uses the given inputs (`string` and `subs`) rather than having to create a new thing, namely `replacements`.

```
string.split(//).map{ |l| subs[l] || [l] }.inject(&:product).map{ |a| a.flatten.join }
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you include more than one character in the subs e.g. here's two characters with the "oo" e.g. subs = {"oo" => ["oo", "00"], "a" => ["a", "@"], "i" => ["i", "!"], "s" => ["s", "$", "&"]}